# bug in phone number validation

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to write code for phone number validation. I need to just check whether it is a numeric value. I used the following code.

```
var phoneres
function checkphone(int){
    var filter=/^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{7}$/
    if (filter.test(int))
        phoneres=true
    else {
        phoneres=false
    }
    return (phoneres)
}

if(checkemail(document.getElementById('phone').value) == false) {
    alert("Please enter a valid Phone number!");
    return false;
}
```

Even i enter the valid number example 111-1234567 it displays `"Please enter a valid Phone number!"`.

How can i correct that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are calling the `checkemail` instead of `checkphone` function